# Firefox 108.0 doesn't start without --migration parameter

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 22.04

This just started a couple of days ago; I don't think FF was updated very recently.

About 3 weeks or so ago, I finally got irritated enough with snap bugging me about updates and removed it, then re-installed via apt (I followed the instructions [found here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04); basically, 1. Add mozilla ppa, 2. prioritize it over snap, 3. uninstall FF via `snap`, and 4. install FF via `apt`). It's been working fine since, until this issue.

Chrome works fine. I'm using nouveau drivers with X11 in Plasma. I've turned off hardware acceleration. I've tried creating a new, empty profile, but that doesn't change anything so I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with the profile.

What's weird is that in the process of playing around with profiles and safe mode, I've discovered that it *will* open from CLI - with my original profile - but only if I add `--migration`. I started with trying to get some logs, but all the log files are completely empty and there's nothing useful in the console. I tried `--safe-mode` which I thought was helpful, but that of course disables all the extensions and I need at least a couple of them for work. So I tried with just `--migration` - and it loads. I have to select "Don't import anything" in the dialog, which is a nuisance, and my desktop/application menu icons don't work (unless, of course, I add `--migration` to the command). I've also tried actually migrating from the new profile, but nothing's changed - I still can't open FF without the `--migration` parameter. Note that this is the only parameter: I'm not adding `--safe-mode` here.

How can I get this to work correctly?

Edit: There is nothing in `~/snap/firefox` (other than `current`).

Edit 2: Appears to be resolved in FF 109.0.

Comment: How exactly did you reinstall firefox via apt? Please edit your question to add the exact steps you made to do this.

Comment: @mook765, thanks, done. I hope that's enough detail.

Comment: Yes, it is. Have you tried to reinstall firefox (`sudo apt reinstall firefox`)? Probably worth a try.

Comment: I did, and there was no difference.